# If we don't add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription for saving images to Photo library, would it be rejected from App Store review

Tags: plist, appstore-approval

I am trying to save photos to PhotoLibrary from my app. While saving I am checking whether user has given permission to do so, otherwise I am asking the user to go to settings and turn the permission on. If the permission has been given only, I am saving the photos. For this I am using PHPhotLibray requestAuthorization() method and so NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in my info.plist.
Because of these checks that I do in my app, there is no chance of crash even if I don't add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key in info.plist. But my concern is whether it will be rejected from the App Store review.Can anyone help me with this scenario?